# channel.recv() maximum return size

Tags: python, paramiko

sh route has 8000-10000 routes when I am trying to fetch it using `channel.recv(99999)`

I am unable to get complete output, please suggest any way to read complete output.

Comment: Can't you use a loop?

Comment: Show us your code! + *"sh route has 8000-10000 routes"* makes little sense to us.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are running a command which has a lot of output, and you expect to receive it all in one go, with:

```
channel.recv(99999)
```

But that's not how it works.  Buffers have a finite size, and once that's reached you'll probably have to call `recv()` again to continue reading from the channel.

Comment: soo true, buffer will always have finite size, the issue that was putting in it loop was not allowing me to read from where last recv()left.